# Why can't I access the value of the class variable as the class variables are initialized at the time of object creation

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compilation

```java
class  Bill{
    int billid;
    // **setter for the variable**
    public void setbillid(int i){
        billid=i;
    }

    // **getter for the variable**
    public int getbillid(){
        return billid;
    }
}
```

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // **This below is generating the error**  
        Bill b = new Bill();
        System.out.println(b.getbillid);
    }
}
```

**symbol:   variable setbillid**

**location: variable b of type Bill**

Comment: b.getbillid is a method, not variable. You syntax is wrong, should be b.getbillid()

Answer (score 1):

the error message is wrong - it should be

> symbol: variable getbillid

and not `setbillid`

:-)

---

You can choose:

use the method: `System.out.println(b.getbillid());`

or the variable (not recommended): `System.out.println(b.billid);`
(assuming it is accessible)

---

Anyway, since the setter was not called, it will have its initial value: `0`\

I would like to recommend to use the usual naming conventions (`getBillId`, `setBillId`, `billId`,...)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(b.getbillid());
```

`getbillid()` is a method that returns `Billid`. The right way to call a method is `objectName.methodName()` and variable is `objectName.variableName`.